# sending OSC (open sound control) messages from an android application

Tags: java, android, osc, javaosc

I'm writing an android application using the SDK for android 4.0

I wonder if there is an API for sending OSC messages (Open Sound Control) 
in the android SDK or should I just use the java OSC SDK.

I tried browsing the http://opensoundcontrol.org/introduction-osc
and under implementations I found the following: http://www.illposed.com/software/javaosc.html

so I just wonder if I should use JavaOSC, some other library or if maybe android comes with it's own API for sending OSC messages.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

kfir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, there is no API within Android itself to broadcast OSC messages. And **yes** it seems that currently the only way is JavaOSC.

Here is an app, [FingerPlay MIDI](http://thesundancekid.net/blog/fingerplay-midi/), which uses OSC message in order to communicate over WIFI. Check its source code at http://code.google.com/p/fingerplaymidi/source/browse/ and find out how to use JavaOSC in your code.

Comment: Anything fresh to this? Google Code is dead since years now…
as is your App site…

Answer (score 3):

Here is library I wrote specifically with Android in mind.

https://github.com/alistairrutherford/osc-tools

I have a sample application which uses this here.

https://github.com/alistairrutherford/tonome

Answer (score 1):

My solution was used Processing IDE in Android Mode with the library OscP5.